# Implement query.magnific-popup.js in dreamweaver cs5. Syntax error in original code

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm new to using magnific popup and I'm trying to implement query.magnific-popup.js in dreamweaver cs5. I did not change a thing in the original syntax of this file but get a syntax error in:

`<meta name="selected-link" value="repo_source" data-pjax-transient />`

I also placed a test image with syntax online and this simply works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="www.youtube.com/iframe_api" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="www.youtube.com/iframe_api" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="topnav">
            <div id="topnav-links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="flexstay.html">Flexstay</a></li>
                    <li><a href="flexpack.html">Flexpack</a></li>
                    <li><a href="flexchoice.html">Flexchoice</a></li>
                    <li><a href="flexclusives.html">Flexclusives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="friends.html">Friends</a></li>
                    <li><a href="guiding-car-coach.html">Guiding | Car | Coach</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

       <a class="popup" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_b.jpg" title="This image fits only horizontally.">
       <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_s.jpg" height="75" width="75"></a>

    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image', closeOnContentClick: true,
    image: {
    verticalFit: false
    }
    });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance.